# is it possible to get an alert when application went down?

Tags: websphere

I am using WebSphere 6.2 and my requirement is I admin have to get an alert when the application on the server stopped or server down .. How to achieve this ?   In higher versions this feature is there ? please help me

Thanks in Advance ,
Raj

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you expect WebSphere to send a message to you when the server it's running on is shut down?

Comment: When you say "WebSphere 6.2", is this "WebSphere _Process Server_", "WebSphere _Application Server_", or something else? (I presume it's WebSphere Process Server since that's the only one that has a version 6.2 to my knowledge..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean WebSphere application server processes (rather than the physical server on which WebSphere is running) and individual applications running on those processes. I'm also assuming you mean when those elements have stopped unexpectedly rather than when somebody has deliberately stopped them.

If so, you're going to have to use external monitoring software to detect most of those conditions. We use a combination of scripts that scan for processes and specific error messages in logs and external site-monitoring software that checks for application responsiveness. Such scripts can be standalone, handwritten scripts, or run under generic monitoring tools from IBM (Tivoli) or 3rd-parties.

Alternatively, I think you should also be able to write something that uses JMX to read specific things about WebSphere state, and there is at least one sophisticated monitoring tool you could purchase, IBM Tivoli Composite Application Manager (ITCAM) for Application Diagnostics, which can monitor WebSphere internals.

Comment: @ dbreaux you are right .. I am talking about websphere application server and the application deployed on the server .. thanks for your Reply